# What should be proper event type of handleChange and handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is my codesandbox links,
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-banach-gf35mn?file=/src/App.tsx:643-655

I am not getting the proper event types,
Here is my try:

```
const handleChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target as
      | HTMLInputElement
      | HTMLTextAreaElement;
    setNewTask((prev) => ({ ...prev, id: Date.now(), [name]: value }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!newTask.title) return;
    setAllTasks((prev) => [newTask, ...prev]);
    setNewTask({ id: 0, title: "", description: "" });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the `event` type from `ChangeEventHandler` to `ChangeEvent`
Because `ChangeEventHandler` is for the entire Handler function.
But for the `event` object the type was `ChangeEvent`.

That's what the error msg was saying!

[Modified Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-item-with-optional-details-input-delete-items-forked-w5116e?file=/src/App.tsx)